# Python console with a remote interpreter can't take input in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to remote development with PyCharm. I have an remote environment set up, and it is working fine with one exception, not able to take user input in the console. In running the following statement in the console, the console becomes blocked, and I am prompted "Previous command is still running. Please wait or press Control+C in console to interrupt."

`s = input('Enter a value: ')`

Executing any file that uses the `input()` function in the console exhibits the same problem but only with a different message. The message in this case is "Console is not enabled."

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. My local host is a Mac, my remote host is Ubuntu 16 with a Python virtual environment created by Conda.

Comment: Do you see `print`s from your remote environment on your local stdout?

Comment: @Darkonaut Yes, I do. The statement `print('hello')` prints hello in the console.

Comment: Does it also if you write `print('hello')` directly in the console and not just in your script?

Comment: @Darkonaut Yes.

Comment: Strange, because your issue sounded like stdin is set to the remote environment. Maybe when you go into PyCharms settings, check if your Interpreter listed under "Project" is the same like under "Build, Execution\Console\Python Console".

Comment: @Darkonaut I just checked again. They are the same.

Comment: what does `sys.stdin.__dict__` give you in the console?

Comment: @Darkonaut It is `{'encoding': 'UTF-8', 'original_stdin': <_pydev_bundle.pydev_console_utils.BaseStdIn object at 0x7f7198543438>, 'interpreter': <pydevconsole.InterpreterInterface object at 0x7f719844ff28>, 'client_port': 37957, 'host': '127.0.0.1'}`

Comment: I don't get how this could end up in your observed behaviour. Maybe this here helps you [pycharm-configure-pythonpath-in-remote-interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602442/pycharm-configure-pythonpath-in-remote-interpreter). If not I suggest you file a ticket here [youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)

Comment: @Darkonaut Do you see anything wrong with the value of `sys.stdin.__dict__` I posted?

Comment: Not that I could say. I wanted to see host and it's local. But maybe that shouldn't be in for a remote environment? I'm just guessing here because of the absence of somebody who is more knowledgable, I have never worked with remote environments. It's probably some path issue which is not set, but I can't point you to a solution.[python-console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/python-console.html)

Comment: This is still an active issue 4 years later
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29157